# QuickFIX/J FileStore

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

In Java is there a way to save quickfix sequence numbers in memory or fast saving instead of a file on disk?
Sometimes there is a latency in saving sequence numbers in files which results in a mismatch of sequence numbers between client and server when there is a restart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store messages and sequence numbers in memory you need to use a `MemoryStore` which can be obtained through `quickfix.MemoryStoreFactory`.